# Find azure sql database backup size

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-sql-database

Is there a way to find the size of a database backup inside azure elastic pool ?

I need it to help me find the price of each database inside the elastic pool using azure calculator.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way you can do that.

To see how much I spend per database I usually go into SQL Databases > Compute + Storage, but as you can see, when the database is inside an Elastic Pool you cannot see the price:

[image]

You can see the total price of the whole pool but not of one database.

A better approach is to go to Elastic Pool > Overview > databases, and have an overview of the consumption of each database.

[image]

Now try to see what the price of the each core and each Gb.

Try to create a rule that share the cost of the Elastic Pool per number of Avg CPU, Peak CPU, Data space used